# Booting stops on black screen with some texts after upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, temperature

Yesterday (14.08.2018), a popup on Ubuntu 16.04 showed up and suggested to upgrade to 18.04. After upgrading ( it took several hours), I rebooted the laptop (ASUS U36S) and it showed the black screen with some notices about services.

The last one is different on every boot: currently it is "Started Network   Manager Script Dispatcher". Then it eventually said that "Core/Package temperature above threshold.". How to fix it?

[image]

[image]

Here is yet another trial to boot:

[image]

Comment: Related: [CPU hardware errors in Ubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/941686/250300) Shutting the computer down and letting it cool down before powering on again might help.

Comment: did you install 'lm_sensors' for check cooling the system? i think you purge that package before booting sir.

Comment: For "apt install lm-sensors", it says 
 "no installation candidate". After cleaning from inside and outside and placing icebags under the laptop, it stays on saying  "Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service" for all the day (6 hours so far).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CPU hardware errors in Ubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/941686/cpu-hardware-errors-in-ubuntu-17-04)

Answer (score 1):

Your computer is overheating during the boot process and hardware problems can rarely be solved by software, but still:

- if there is a BIOS setting to lower the CPU frequency, set it to the lowest setting possible
- If that's impossible, put the laptop in a *sealed* plastic bag (ziploc) in the freezer for 20 minutes, try to boot it and execute the following commands as root or with sudo privileges:

  ```
  apt install lm-sensors
  sensors
  ```

that way all sensors in your PC will be activated and TurBo Boost can kick in.

```
    apt install pm-utils
    pm-powersave true
```

which will also put your computer in a low power state.

#### But the real advice is to [take it apart](https://www.how-fixit.com/laptop-repair-guides/asus-laptop/asus-u36/), clean it out with a vacuum cleaner and alcohol (200° proof) and put it back together.

Comment: It did not help.

Comment: What did not help?  taking it apart and cleaning it out???

Comment: Yes. For "apt install lm-sensors", it answers "no installation candidate". After cleaning the laptop from inside and outside and placing icebags under it, the screen stays on saying "Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service" for all the day (6 hours so far).

Comment: OK, so the temperature problem is gone.  Now it becomes a problem of a simple black screen only.  Let me look for the duplicate and close.  If you want, you can accept the answer for getting rid of the Temperature problem.

Comment: CPU temperature was not the reason, but the aftermath of the problem. I reinstalled Ubuntu 16.

Comment: What was the problem then?  (The cleaning did lower the T°, not?)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a long time ago. Watching this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTmZYzaxR_k&t=87s) helped me, but I will try to explain it step by step.

In grub press e. This will enable you to enable the grub menu. If you can't see grub, press the shift key as you are booting. To see it permanently you will have to follow these [steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time).

Look for the word "splash". Go to the end of that line and type "nomodeset".

Next type CTRL + X to save your settings.

That's it. She goes a little more in depth about how set up graphics card drivers, but it is a short video. I hope this helps.

Comment: It did not help.