# Ubuntu 18.10 Not booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia

I am new to Ubuntu so please don't Tag "has been answered before" and tag some answer that only veterans understand.
I have Ubuntu for several days now when I decided to install steam (didn't work at all but that's not my problem). I then decided to upgrade or update my NVidia driver (for gtx750ti if that matters). Ubuntu then asked me to setup some MOK Password (whatever that is, I didn't find a pleasant explanation) in order to do something with the driver at the next boot. So I did. Then I restarted the PC, was asked for the password, typed it in 2 times correctly (I am 100% sure) with this blue window telling me it was wrong. On the third try I tried to type it in on my German keyboard as if it was an American (just in case) and naturally that didn't work. So then I continued the normal boot, where I was asked
Ubuntu
Actions for Ubuntu (or so)
Windows boot (or so)
System setup

Ah yes, I have Ubuntu install Dualboot with windows (please forgive me if I am using some wrong terminology).
So I selected Ubuntu and saw the normal Ubuntu logo (which was wierd because it was always stretched before for a few seconds). Then I got a black screen with a blinking underline cursor in the top left corner. And nothing happened. I turned my system off again by holding the power button. A second before it actually went off, i saw some letters and digits where the cursor was before. I tried that a few times and even tried recovery mode of 18.10 and 18.13 (or 18.10.3). I didn't want to do anything that I don't understand because I was afraid I could lose windows as well.
So when I see
Ubuntu
Actions for Ubuntu (or so)
Windows boot (or so)
System setup
Is that the boot already or is the boot where I am stuck?
Also I have read something about GRUB online but I have no idea if that could help me or what it is or how I access it.

Comment: Is your computer getting hot also?  [this is a very similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065564/booting-stops-on-black-screen-with-some-texts-after-upgrading-ubuntu-to-18-04)

Comment: @Charles Green Never in 4 Years it overheated. I did not even overclock my cpu

Comment: Found the answer. Was a problem with nvidia driver. Please vote for duplicate, preferably if you can confirm that this was the real problem

Comment: If it worked, then it was probably the solution!