# "core temperature above threshold, CPU clock throttled" causing Dell G7 laptop to freeze intermittently on 20.04

Tags: 20.04, dell, overheating

I have a Dell G7 15 7590 laptop.  I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.

Now one to two times a day the computer freezes.  Sometimes it comes back and sometimes I think a full restart is required.

`cat /var/log/syslog` shows:

```
Jun 30 15:11:49 WORKCOM900 kernel: [45679.456318] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Queue 0 is inactive on fifo 2 and stuck for 2500 ms. SW [87, 88] HW [162, 162] FH TRB=0x0a5a5a5a2
Jun 30 15:11:52 WORKCOM900 kernel: [45685.904752] mce: CPU4: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 305)
Jun 30 15:11:52 WORKCOM900 kernel: [45685.904752] mce: CPU10: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 305)
Jun 30 15:11:52 WORKCOM900 kernel: [45685.904752] mce: CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3184)
Jun 30 15:11:52 WORKCOM900 kernel: [45685.904752] mce: CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3184)
Jun 30 15:11:52 WORKCOM900 kernel: [45685.904752] mce: CPU11: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3184)
Jun 30 15:11:52 WORKCOM900 kernel: [45685.904752] mce: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3184)
Jun 30 15:11:52 WORKCOM900 kernel: [45685.904471] mce: CPU9: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3184)
Jun 30 15:11:52 WORKCOM900 kernel: [45685.904196] mce: CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3184)
Jun 30 15:11:52 WORKCOM900 kernel: [45685.904752] mce: CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3184)
Jun 30 15:11:52 WORKCOM900 kernel: [45685.904752] mce: CPU10: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3184)
Jun 30 15:11:52 WORKCOM900 kernel: [45685.904195] mce: CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3184)
Jun 30 15:11:52 WORKCOM900 kernel: [45685.904195] mce: CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3184)
Jun 30 15:11:52 WORKCOM900 kernel: [45685.904752] mce: CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3184)
Jun 30 15:11:52 WORKCOM900 kernel: [45685.904752] mce: CPU10: Core temperature/speed normal
Jun 30 15:11:52 WORKCOM900 kernel: [45685.904752] mce: CPU4: Core temperature/speed normal
Jun 30 15:11:52 WORKCOM900 kernel: [45685.904752] mce: CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
```

Each time it freezes there are similar messages in `/var/log/syslog`

Perhaps it is is somehow related to the wifi?

I tried every suggestion in this [CPU hardware errors in Ubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/941686/cpu-hardware-errors-in-ubuntu-17-04) and nothing worked.

I see other issues have been raised [here on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1851749) and [here on the Arch Linux forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=248075)

There are no issues with this laptop when running Windows and the laptop is brand new so I do not think it is a problem with the thermal paste or hardware issues.

I am almost always running the Chrome browser, but it does not seem tied to anything specific (i.e. CPU intensive tasks or GPU intensive tasks) and it has happened when I am not running Chrome as well.

Does anyone have any suggestions for me to try?

I have tried to run this with the nVidia 440 driver and the Nouveau driver and it happens in both circumstances.

Comment: I've seen a lot of overheating posts with 20.04 on laptops, usually related to nvidia drivers or lack there of.

Comment: See also: https://superuser.com/questions/1160735/stop-dell-from-throttling-cpu-with-power-adapter

Comment: Does the CPU fan spin normally?

Comment: @hextech I hear my CPU fan so I am assuming it is spinning correctly.

Comment: You talk about possible **thermal** issues but I do not see any temperatures information! Please, report them (see *lm_sensors* to begin with...)